# Pytube keyerror 'streamData' while downloading a video

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I was writing a code to see available streams of the video by writing below code

```
from pytube import Playlist
from pytube import YouTube as YT
import threading as th
import time

plist=input('Enter the playlist: ')

videos=list(Playlist(plist))
i=videos[0]
video=YT(i)
strm=video.streams.filter(res="720p")
print(strm)
```

from above code I got error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Practicals\Python\ML\youtube\temp.py", line 11, in <module>
    strm=video.streams.filter(res="720p")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 176, in fmt_streams
    stream_manifest = extract.apply_descrambler(self.streaming_data)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 161, in streaming_data
    return self.vid_info['streamingData']
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'streamingData'
```

Comment: I am getting the same problem for every video

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding the **use_oauth** and **allow_oauth_cache** attributes to YT(i).

```
from pytube import Playlist
from pytube import YouTube as YT
import threading as th
import time

plist=input('Enter the playlist: ')

videos=list(Playlist(plist))
i=videos[0]
video=YT(i, use_oauth=True, allow_oauth_cache=True)
strm=video.streams.filter(res="720p")
print(strm)
```

This will require you to connect to youtube via your browser once, but then it will allow you to download the videos.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks so much! However, how can we get that response instead of it being printed to the console. The issue is I am using it to a tkinter app, hence the user cannot see the prompt and instruction as it is printed in the console. Thanks again

Answer (score 7):

Got the same error while using pytube 12.1.2.

```
video=YT(i, use_oauth=True, allow_oauth_cache=True)
```

did not work for me.

After upgrading pytube (to 15.0.0), the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
from pytube import Playlist
from pytube import YouTube as YT
import threading as th
import time

DOWNLOAD_DIR = 'C:\\download\\folder'

plist=input('Enter a playlist URL: ')

videos=list(Playlist(plist))

for i in range(len(videos)):
    print(i,'-',videos[i])

    video   = YT(videos[i], use_oauth=True, allow_oauth_cache=True)
    stream  = video.streams.get_by_itag(140)
    stream.download(output_path=DOWNLOAD_DIR)
    
print('----------done---------')
```

Comment: This seems to repeat the solution by linomassaro an hour prior, except without any explanation.

Comment: Okay i will try

Comment: The other answer is not an _hour_ earlier, but a _day_ earlier. Please don't repeat answers.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the begining of the script. 
This has done the job for me [even after a long time].

```
import os
os.system('cmd /c "pip install --upgrade pytube"')
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

First locate pytube library location

[image]

Click on "innertube.py" and edit the code on line 78 replacing client='ANDROID' with client='WEB'

[image]

It worked pretty well for me